# How can i deploy ssrs report one server to another server

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008-r2

When I create a sample ssrs report and I deploy it, I get the following error:

> The specified report server URL http://localhost/reports could not be
>   found. verify the syntax of the URL and that report server exits.

Comment: Why are you using `localhost` in your URL?

Answer (score 2):

The URL you are currently using is for the report *manager*.
Report RDLs are deployed to the report server URL, so change the path to `http://localhost/reportserver`.

Alternatively, you can find the correct URL for your server configuration in the Reporting Services Configuration Manager > Web Service URL (generally located in the Start menu > All Programs > Microsoft SQL Server {Version} > Configuration Tools).

For more information: [TechNet: How To Publish Reports](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159615%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)